# CSS layout block below previous block

Tags: html, css

How to make third block below the first?

Now third block below second.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/SdR6e/1/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 400px;">
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                First
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 100px;">
                Second
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                Third
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                Fourth
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

CSS

```
    .semiblock {
        border: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        width: 198px;
    }​
```

I need this:

[image]

Comment: only html and css? or jQuery code is accepted?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri only html & css, thx for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Try to insert `clear:both` like this:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SdR6e/7/)**

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 400px;">
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                First
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 100px;">
                Second
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                Third
            </div>

            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                Fourth
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

CSS:

```
        .semiblock {
            border: 1px solid black;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            width: 198px;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

​

Comment: some blocks can be absent, so I can't use it to certain blocks

Comment: Well your question is to make the third block below the first, explain well your problem and we can help you if thi solution isn't what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SdR6e/2/

Use `clear:both;` when you want next element below another element.

If you use this with multiple blocks then write it in a class and add class to target elements.

```
.clearall{
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, some blocks can be absent

Comment: OP didn't ask anything about 4th block :)

Comment: my bad, 4th block must be like 3rd in my example :D Also some blocks can be absent, so I can't use it to certain blocks

Answer (score 0):

Method of  "Alessandro Minoccheri" is good (+1),

but you want , also, just add "clear:left" value in your third block :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 400px;">
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                First
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 100px;">
                Second
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height:200px;clear:left;">
                Third
            </div>
            <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
                Fourth
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately some blocks can be absent, so I can't use it to certain blocks

Comment: Hi, Ok, but how many blocks have you? 4 it's just for sample? and have you just two column? or you can have many colums and many lines?

Comment: Hi :D, I have about 4 blocks, and 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Please use below HTML.. and used same CSS OR i have updated your given fiddle. Please check it using below URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/SdR6e/11/

```
    <div style="width: 400px;">
        <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
            First
        </div>
        <div class="semiblock" style="height: 100px;">
            Second
        </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
        <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
            Third
        </div>
        <div class="semiblock" style="height: 200px;">
            Fourth
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: unfortunately some blocks can be absent, so I can't use it before certain blocks